# alert() is running before my own alertbox() function - why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have one my own function named `alertbox()`. I am calling this first then I am calling `alert()`. However the `alert()` is being displayed before the `alertbox()` is running. Why is this happening?

I expect that `alertbox()` runs first then the `alert()`.

```js
alertbox('Confirm to Cancel?', 'Confirmation');
alert(alertbox_clicked_button_id);

var alertbox_clicked_button_id = '';

function alertbox(alert_text, alert_header = 'INFORMATION', alert_truebutton = 'Yes', alert_falsebutton = 'No') {
  $('#alert-header').text('');
  $('#alert-body').text('');
  $('#alert-truebutton').hide();
  $('#alert-falsebutton').hide();

  var xalert_text = alert_text;
  var xalert_header = alert_header.toUpperCase();
  var xalert_color = '';
  var waitingtime = 5000;

  if (xalert_header == 'ERROR' || xalert_header == 'E') {
    xalert_header = 'ERROR';
    xalert_color = 'red';
    waitingtime = 0;
  } else if (xalert_header == 'SUCCESS' || xalert_header == 'S') {
    xalert_header = 'SUCCESS';
    xalert_color = 'green';
  } else if (xalert_header == 'INFORMATION' || xalert_header == 'I') {
    xalert_header = 'INFORMATION';
    xalert_color = 'teal';
  } else if (xalert_header == 'MESSAGE' || xalert_header == 'M') {
    xalert_header = 'MESSAGE';
    xalert_color = 'blue';
  } else if (xalert_header == 'WARNING' || xalert_header == 'W') {
    xalert_header = 'WARNING';
    xalert_color = 'purple';
  } else if (xalert_header == 'CONFIRMATION' || xalert_header == 'C') {
    waitingtime = 0;
    xalert_header = 'CONFIRMATION';
    xalert_color = 'green';
    $('#alert-truebutton').show();
    $('#alert-falsebutton').show();
    $('#alert-truebutton').html(alert_truebutton);
    $('#alert-falsebutton').html(alert_falsebutton);
  }

  $('#alert-body').html(xalert_text);
  $('#alert-header').text(xalert_header);
  $('#alert-header-div').css('background-color', xalert_color);
  $('#alert-closebutton').css('background-color', xalert_color);
  //$('#alertmodal').modal('show');

  if (waitingtime > 0) {
    AutoCloseDialogBox(waitingtime);
  }
}

function AutoCloseDialogBox(WaitSeconds) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#alertmodal').modal('hide');
    alertbox_clicked_button_id = 'alert-closebutton';
  }, WaitSeconds);
}

function alertfunction(pass_id) {
  $('#alertmodal').modal('hide');
  alertbox_clicked_button_id = pass_id;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks for the string "CONFIRMATION", but you are passing "Confirmation". Those are not equal.

Comment: Also what's probably happening is that the browser is delaying the updates to the DOM (for your alert box) until the event loop finishes, so the `alert()` happens before you actually *see* the DOM changes.

Comment: Also, it's likely that the `alert()` will block the UI from being updated, therefore any DOM operation (which is by comparison very slow) will not happen until the `alert()` is dismissed. It's a very, *very* odd situation to be using a custom modal AND an alert as well. Usually you'd want to avoid the standard `alert()`, because frankly, they're ugly and lazy

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to PHP? You haven't shared any such code

Comment: Thank you Pointy, RoyMcCrossan for your kind concern. Nico Hasse there is no PHP code as of right now. I checked all the links and advise which is given here. All are correct but using the inbuilt alert(). I shall try again with AJAX if possible. Thanks again to all of you